# Documentation of MongoDB Functions for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm confused. I tried to use the `findAndModify` function of a collection in NodeJS as it was stated in the official MongoDB documentation:

```
db.collection('myColl').findAndModify(
    {
        query: {
            itemId: ObjectID(itemId),
            requesterId: requesterId
        },
        remove: 1
    },
    function(err, found){ 
        console.log(err, found);
    });
```

It works fine in the console. But in NodeJS I retrieve an error. The error message told me, I have to provide at least one update or remove. There were some similar questions here on StackOverflow where one of the answers mentioned to use `findAndRemove` instead.

Okay, but as I searched for a documentation for `findAndRemove` I haven't found anything helpful. Also, my IDE (WebStorm) marks that method as deprecated. Through the autocomplete, I've also found the function `findOneAndDelete` which isn't marked as deprecated and seems to do what I want, but I cannot find anything about that function.

Since, I am quite new to NodeJS as well as MongoDB, this stuff is really confusing and I'm very disappointed of this documentation.

My question is: What is the background? Where can I find a useful documentation for the JavaScript API of MongoDB or how to use the MongoDB documentation correctly? Where can I get information on the above-mentioned method?

Comment: What mongodb module are you using? Can you provide the documentation you are reading?

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findAndModify

Comment: have you included `var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID` ?

Comment: 1. I'm using the native drivers of MongoDB (`require('mongodb')`)
2. Yes, I've included ObjectID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using the node MongoDB driver.

You can find the documentation of the findAndModify function, aswell as  Inserting and updating functions here:

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

Answer (score 3):

There are many Node.js modules act to connect and manage a MongoDB server.

The native one is this: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

But you can use also the most popular one Mongoose: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose

Said that I think your code is wrong it should be:

```
db.collection('myColl').findAndModify({
    itemId: ObjectID(itemId),
    requesterId: requesterId
}, null, null, {
    remove: 1
},
function(err, found) {
    console.log(err, found);
});
```

As stated in the doc: `findAndModify(query, sort, doc, options, callback)`

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection('myColl').findAndModify(
   { itemId: ObjectID(itemId), requesterId: requesterId },
   {}, //Do an update here if you want
   { remove: true }, // Remove the doc
   function (err, doc) {
      // do things 
   }
);
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#example